# jquery mobile ios/android page load order

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, hyperlink, pageload

I have a problem loading the page, first the header is loaded, then "content" without list, and finally the "footer". After loading the list into "content", the list moves "footer" at bottom of page.

As I can have it load first the "header", after the "content" with the list, and finally the footer at bottom of page.

I want to prevent the footer moves at bottom of page when the list loads into "content".

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

cant u hide the footer and show it when the list has loaded?

Comment: Yes, but the best solution, I think, it's first load header and footer and after the list.
I try to do this and explain the visual effect.

Thanks.